# Given an orthogonal matrix, how can I find a second orthogonal matrix that gives a product of zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Assume I have some orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{Q}^\text{T}\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I}$, How can I find a second orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{S}^\text{T}\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{I}$ that gives a product of zero, i.e

$$
\mathbf{Q}^\text{T}\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{S}^\text{T}\mathbf{Q} =  \mathbf{0}
$$
I've read about the null space matrix. If $\mathbf{S}$ is the null space matrix of $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ is orthonormal, then is $\mathbf{S}$ also orthonormal.

Comment: If you read about nullspace, then you should also know that to have a nullspace at least one of the eigenvalues of the matrix should be $0$, which is not the case for orthonormal matrices

Comment: $\det(\mathbf{Q}^\text{T}\mathbf{S})=\det(\mathbf Q)\det(\mathbf S)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

You can't: both matrices $Q$ and $S$ (and their transposes) are invertible, so their product is also invertible and hence can't be the zero matrix.

About the second question: The null space of $Q$ is $\{0\}$, so the null space matrix would be $[0]$ which is not orthonormal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The rows (columns) of $Q,S$ form an orthonormal basis for the space.

So, if you take any non-zero vector $s$, $Qs$ is non-zero in at least one coordinate (since you're writing $s$ in the basis given by $Q$'s rows). Now, apply this idea to $Q^T S$ or $S^T Q$ and you see its impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Any orthogonal matrix is nonsingular, and cannot have a product of zero with any nonzero matrix.